# Showing JSON on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm outputting JSON on to my page, I wish to put it all into an input using .val() but all I get out to the input is:

[Object object]

How can I get the JSON in to the input so the user can see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**JSON.stringify()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Try:

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data) // assuming `data` is the JSON object.
myInput.val(jsonStr)
```

Then either log or display the `jsonStr` text.

Answer (score 0):

You have the json object right? Lets say it's name is "jsonData" - try .val(jsonData.toString())